# Custom validation plugin fails with multiple table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to self create a validation that compares Gross and Tare values in the table using jQuery validation plugin. Tare should always be smaller than Gross.

Here is the JS code:

```
$.validator.addMethod('lessThan', function (value, element, param) {
if (this.optional(element)) return true;
var i = parseInt(value);
var j = parseInt($(param).val());
return i <= j;
}, "Tare must less than Gross");

$('#myForm').validate({rules: {tare: {lessThan: ".gross"}}});
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <table id="lineItemTable">
        <thead>
        <th>
            <tr>
                <td>Gross</td>
                <td>Tare</td>
            </tr>
        </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name='gross' class="gross"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='tare' class="tare"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name='gross' class="gross"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='tare' class="tare"/></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

This code works fine when only have one row involved.
When comes two table rows, it compares the 2nd row tare value with the 1st row gross value. Apparently I want it to compare 2nd row tare value with 2nd row gross value. Also for some reason the error message shows up at the 1st row.

Here is one screen shot:

[image]

Please advise how do I change my code to make it working properly.

And here is the CDN that I am using:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple input elements share the exact same `name` within the same `form`.  The plugin will always fail since I cannot keep track this way.

Comment: @Sparky What would be the solution to this? I am looking into create a table with dynamically adding rows by the user when needed. Is there a way somehow give each row a unique name but not hard-code them?

Comment: The proper solution would be to append an index number to the `name` in order to keep them unique.  Then use the `.rules('add')` method to add the rules every time you create a new row.  There are quite a few examples of this posted on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking for `$('.gross').val()`  will always retrieve the value of the *first* matched element (in the whole document).

Instead, look only in the row containing the element being validated:

```
var j = parseInt($(element).closest('tr').find(param).val());
```

```js
$.validator.addMethod('lessThan', function(value, element, param) {
  console.log(element);
  if (this.optional(element)) return true;
  var i = parseInt(value);
  var j = parseInt($(element).closest('tr').find(param).val());
  return i <= j;
}, "Tare must less than Gross");

$('#myForm').validate({
  rules: {
    tare: {
      lessThan: ".gross"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <table id="lineItemTable">
    <thead>
      <th>
        <tr>
          <td>Gross</td>
          <td>Tare</td>
        </tr>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='gross' class="gross" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='tare' class="tare" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='gross' class="gross" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name='tare' class="tare" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple input elements share the exact same `name` within the same form. The plugin will always fail since it cannot keep track this way. Your answer "appears" to work because the custom method is being forced to look at the other inputs, however, the placement of the error message proves that the plugin thinks it's evaluating the first row.